# How to calculate the third Monday of the month an item is created using a calculated column (date / time)?

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column

How to calculate the third Monday of the month an item is created using a calculated column (date / time)?

I wish to calculate the date based on the created column.

Comment: Third Monday, or third Monday after the entered date? (I.e. what if the date entered is after the third Monday?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
=DATE( YEAR(SomeDate),MONTH(SomeDate),1 )
  +  2 - WEEKDAY( DATE( YEAR(SomeDate),MONTH(SomeDate),1 ) )
  +  14 
  + IF( WEEKDAY( DATE( YEAR(SomeDate),MONTH(SomeDate),1 ) ) > 2, 7, 0)
```

The "2" is for Monday. (twice in the formula)

The 14 is for the third week - 0 for 1st week, 7 for second week, etc.

I.e. (weekNumber - 1 ) * 7

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried this and it is resulting as "1". Where am I going wrong?